# Unity 5, Mesh Text doesn't appear on Game view

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine

Ok so I'm trying to create a Healthbar, with text inside of it.. I also want that text to be contantly changing, so I made a script for it.

```
public TextMesh HealthText;

void Update()
    {
        AdjustCurrentHealth(0);
        HandleMovement();
        HandleHealth();
        Texts();
    }

    private void Texts()
    {
        HealthText.text = CurHealth.ToString() + " / " + MaxHealth.ToString();
    }
```

Well, I can change it on the Unity component settings, and it shows on the scene view, but when I press play, the text doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really see why it wouldn't work. I just tested the same code you have. What I did was:

- Create a new 3D Text game object.
- Assign this object to the public variable (HealthText) of the game object that has your script attached. (VERY IMPORTANT).
- Run the script.

I wonder if the text disappears from the scene view as well when you run?. Maybe this means theres a problem with creating the string.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, it was some kind of bug.. I closed and re-opened and it worked.